# Rails: "link_to" for logging out and deleting session not responding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have an app that allows a user to view blog posts once they are "signed up/ logged in" and saves their `id` in `session[:user_id]`.

The problem I am having is with the "link_to" method for logging out once they are in. In the browser when I hover over the "Logout" link, it doesn't even indicate it's a link, and when clicked it does nothing.

**index.hmtl.erb :controller => blogs**

```
<div ng-controller="BlogController">



  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <h4 class="user_session_signedInAs_txt">
          Signed in as:
          <span class="user_session_email"><%= session[:email]%></span>
        </h4>
        <h4>
          <%= link_to('Logout', {:controller => "users", :action => 'logout'}, :method => :delete, class: "blog_home_logout" ) %>
        </h4>
        <h4 class="search_blogs_heading">Search Blogs</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h6 class="search_blogs_label">Enter "title" or "date"</h6>
        <input type="text" class="search_blogs_input" ng-model="search_blogs" placeholder=" Title or Date" autofocus>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="blog_search_div" ng-repeat="blog in blogs | filter: search_blogs | xFutureDates | limitTo: 15" ng-show="search_blogs">
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="/blog_page?date={{blog.date}}">
          <p class="blog_search_date">{{blog.date}}</p>
          <p class="blog_search_title">{{blog.title}}</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <img class="spa_room_image" src="/assets/SpaTreatmentRoom.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <h4 class="recent_blogs_heading">Recent Blogs</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div ng-repeat="blog in blogs | recentMonths | limitTo:10">
          <a href="/blog_page?date={{blog.date}}">
            <p class="blog_recentBlogs_date">{{blog.date}}</p>
            <p class="blog_recentBlogs_title">{{blog.title}}</p>
            <p class="blog_recentBlogs_description">{{blog.description.trunc(140)}}Read More</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<div class="container-fluid blogs_index">
      <div class="row text-center">
      <h4 class="blog_index_heading">Recent Blogs</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div ng-repeat="blog in blogs | recentMonths | limitTo:10">
          <a href="/blog_page?date={{blog.date}}">
            <h6 class="archives_index_blog_title">{{blog.title}}</h6>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
      <h4 class="blog_index_heading">Categories</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="blog_category_div">
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Body Contouring'">Body Contouring</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Breast Reduction Liposuction'">Breast Reduction Liposuction</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Breast Reduction Surgery'">Breast Reduction Surgery</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Cosmetic Surgery'">Cosmetic Surgery</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Cosmetic Surgery Procedures'">Cosmetic Surgery Procedures</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Facelift'">Facelift</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Fat Grafting'">Fat Grafting</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Gynecomastia'">Gynecomastia</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Infographics'">Infographics</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Laser Lift'">Laser Lift</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Laser Liposuction'">Laser Liposuction</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Liposuction'">Liposuction</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Liposuction Surgery'">Male Breast Reduction</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Neck Liposuction'">Neck Liposuction</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Non-Invasive Procedures'">Non-Invasive Procedures</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Plastic Surgeons'">Plastic Surgeons</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Plastic Surgery'">Plastic Surgery</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='SmartLipo'">SmartLipo</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='SmartLipo Triplex'">SmartLipo Triplex</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_category_links"><a href="/blog_category_archive?category='Weight Loss'">Weight Loss</a></h6>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container-fluid blog_index">
  <div class="row text-center">
      <h4 class="blog_index_heading">Archives</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='October 2015'">October 2015</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='September 2015'">September 2015</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='August 2015'">August 2015</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='July 2015'">July 2015</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='June 2015'">June 2015</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='May 2015'">May 2015</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='October 2014'">October 2014</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='September 2014'">September 2014</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='August 2014'">August 2014</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='July 2014'">July 2014</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='June 2014'">June 2014</a></h6>
      <h6 class="blog_months_links"><a href="/blog_month_archive?month_year='May 2014'">May 2014</a></h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>




</div>
```

**Controller users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  ... 



  def logout
    session[:user_id] = nil
    session[:email] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "Logged out."
    redirect_to(:action => "login" )
  end


    private
  def message_params
    return params.require(:user).permit( :email, :password, :password_confirmation )
  end

end
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...

  # Users login/signup
  get '/blog_signup' => 'users#new'
  post 'blog_signup' => 'users#create'
  get '/blog_login' => 'users#login'
  post 'blog_attempt_login' => 'users#attempt_login'
  get '/user/blog_logout' => 'users#logout'

  # User_Admins login/signup
  get '/admin_login' => 'user_admins#login'
  post 'admin_attempt_login' => 'user_admins#attempt_login'
  get '/admin_logout' => 'user_admins#logout'

end
```

**Source view through DOM for "link_to"**

```
<a class="blog_home_logout" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/user/blog_logout">Logout</a>
```

**I have changed the route to match the `a` tag**

Comment: Have you tried validating your HTML? I'm guessing that this could be caused by a really messed up document. Otherwise include the rendered html in the question.

Comment: Thank you, I updated with the sign up view. Could you elaborate more on validating HTML?

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options

Comment: The HTML seems to check out.

Comment: You said your problem is the logout-link, so sign up view and login view are irrelevant.

Comment: Reload your page and check its source using the DOM inspector in your browser (usually F12 on keyboard for Chrome/Firefox). Does the `a` tag look correct? Update your question and post what you find in there.

Comment: I changed the route to match the `a` tags `href`, but the link is still inaccessible.

Comment: As web Foster said, learn to use the Developer Tools, DOM-Inspector, Firebug, or what else you have on your Browser, you will need it, it will not be your last bug in your career.

Comment: Do you  use Angular? Because there is an ng-controller attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the reason, but it is something that you need to fix:

Some browsers and some proxy's do "prefetching": they call all "normal" links on your page and cache the result, so they can faster respond when you click on them. They may invoke the logout link! So, your logout link should not use the GET-method.

You need to change your logout-link from GET to something different (POST or better DELETE), and of course the corresponding route.

```
<%= link_to('Logout', {:controller => "users", :action => 'logout'}, :method => :delete) %>
```

The link is inside a `div` with a `ng-controller` attribute. If there is an angular app on your page, than it will change links with javascript.

The logout and logout are typically done in a SessionsController and not in the UsersController, as you are not do something to the user-model. (But that is more a style issue.)

Comment: I actually tried this earlier without any luck. I also tried changing the routes and actions to `delete/destroy` instead of `logout` but same thing occurs. Added note: When I try to add another simple link connecting to another page, it does the same thing and is completely inaccessible.

Comment: Moving the `link_to` outside of the `ng-controller` resolved the issue. Thank you for your help.